# Laravel 8 - Push a global middleware component

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In the Router class (Illuminate\Routing\Router), there is a pushMiddlewareToGroup method available. This works neatly for adding a middleware component to a specific group like web or api. However, I don't see any possibility to add a middleware component as global middleware. Two questions:

- Is my assumption that it is not possible to push middleware components to the global group correct?
- If so, is this a design decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global middleware are handled by the Kernel itself. The Kernel has methods for dealing with the global middleware such as `pushMiddleware`:

```
$kernel = app(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$kernel->pushMiddleware(App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class);
```